# WIX Toolset: Delete registry value only on uninstall

Tags: wix, registry

I have an App and a Wix installer for it.
As part of it's logic the App creates a registry value when its running.
I want to delete this registry value on uninstall only, but keep it on upgrade.

I can't find a "WIX" solution to it.
I've tried Custom Action as well, but it doesn't have enough permissions to modify registry.
Value is stored under HKLM (and this shouldn't change).
The App is running as LocalSystem so it can change HKLM.

**P.S.**
I have tried to set this value to empty during the install to try to make use of autocleanup when uninstalling. But I again couldn't make this scenario work with the upgrade. The value gets erased on the upgrade which should not happen in my case.